# How to stop feet from going through floor with movie clips?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm trying to get this walk cycle to work with a movie clip and it's hard to stop the feet from going through the floor. However, when I keyframe the clip to move up when the feet go through, and down when they are parallel to the floor, it has this weird hopping effect.

Here is a gif of it keyframed (sorry about the quality...this site has a 2mb image limit):

[image]

Here is what happens if I leave the z location constant

[image]

Here is a link to the .blend

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUTU2ZJkQT7UCdWYh2Z8MXgfY-HB-3vU/view?usp=sharing

Here is a link to the .mov file (couldn't pack it)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hBfK1ik4euPLOrHYDmD_DM19IxidOQAS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, I can't see any character in the file you share

Comment: Sorry I forgot to pack all into the .blend. Here is a new link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUTU2ZJkQT7UCdWYh2Z8MXgfY-HB-3vU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oh ok it's a movie on a plane, but the movie is not seen, you can't pack a movie, you need to share it as well

Comment: Sorry again, didn't realize you couldn't pack a movie file. I have shared the file now. Thanks

Comment: Your perspective (i.e. camera location and rotation relative to the floor) doesn't seem correct, you need to make sure that the vanishing lines match the perspective of your original movie

Comment: Even then, your character in the video is moving. It will be hard to put it in a 3D scene and move it in the 3D scene while also preserving the visual foot contact on the ground. It would work way better if you overlay it on top of the rendered scene in compositing.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment the video and the 3D scene perspectives don't match. Also you move the plane with the movie which makes him slide on the floor and make his feet go under the floor. You can fix it if you keep the plane still and move down the floor:

[image]